# Ajax call (large image upload) failing without an error in logs using Unicorn server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, unicorn

I'm doing a multiple file upload using Ruby on Rails. It is working for small images (like less than 3 MB). And only one file is uploading if I upload multiple large files (like 10MB) and remaining are failing without going to the controller.

EDIT: Working if I made async : false. But, I need async : true

Any solution for this. I searched a lot of questions, still I'm not able to find an apt solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What application server and web server are you using? Which environment are we speaking of, dev or production?

Comment: I'm using Rails on Unicorn server and running in production environment. I have used timeout 3600000 in unicorn.rb file, thinking that it's got timed-out.